# export user input data to json file php wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

i m developing a word press plugin and want to create a admin panel with html form and once user submit details a success message will appear and a json file with name manifest.json will be created in plugin directory i have just started php .
    this is my form on admin pannel
`

```
<form name="postform" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table style="border:2px solid #444; width:100%;" id="manifestedit">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="abc"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Short Name:</td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name="short_name" placeholder="abc"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Description:</td>
                <td><textarea id="text" rows="5" cols="30" type="text" name="description">Progressive Web App Tool</textarea>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Orientation</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="orientation" placeholder="portrait"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Start_url</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="start_url" placeholder="/"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Display</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="display" placeholder="standalone"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>background_color</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="background_color" placeholder="#fff"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>theme_color</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="theme_color" placeholder="#fff"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>icons</td>
                <td>
                <table id="icondet">
                    <tr>
                    <td>src</td>
                    <td><input type="url" name="src" placeholder="https//:abc/resource/image/addToHome/android-chrome-192x192.png"></td>        </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>sizes</td>
                        <td> <input type="text" name="sizes" placeholder="192x192"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>types</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="types" placeholder="image/png"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit Entry"> </td>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
```

`

`

```
<?php 
$file = dirname(__FILE__).'/manifest-test.json';
// file_put_contents($file, json_encode($_REQUEST));

if( !empty( $_POST ) ){

// convert form data to json format
$postArray = array(
    "name" => $_POST['name'],
        "short_name" => $_POST['short_name'],
        "description" => $_POST['description'],
        "orientation" => $_POST['orientation'],
        "start_url" => $_POST['start_url'],
        "display" => $_POST['standalone'],
        "background_color" => $_POST['background_color'],
        "theme_color" => $_POST['theme_color'],
"icons" => array(
  "src" => $_POST["src"],
    "sizes" => $_POST["sizes"],
      "types" => $_POST["types"]
 ),
); //you might need to process any other post fields you have..
$json = json_encode( $postArray );
file_put_contents( $file, $json);
}
    ?>
```

`

```
when i submit details a json is created
```

`

```
{
    "name": "fnvlkjdfsnbkjdfsn",
    "short_name": "jksfvnkjsnvkjsdfn",
    "description": "nfvakjld",
    "orientation": "ksfvkxnvk",
    "start_url": "knsvklj",
    "display": gfndghdf,
    "background_color": "kxsvnkjsdn",
    "theme_color": "skvnsk",
    "icons": {
        "src": "http:\/\/localhost\/wd-wp\/wp-admin\/admin.php?page=test-plugin%2Fmenuform.php",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "types": "nblkjvzf"
    }
}
```

`

after some time it reload and all value set to null this is my admin panel look like
ps: i;m just getting started in php need you help so badly

Comment: I don't understand the description of the problem. Are you trying to make the form "sticky" so that after you submit it you can still see the values that you had entered, or are you saying that the data in the JSON file is getting wiped out?

Comment: @NeilGirardi when i submit the data json created but after some time all the value is setting to null moreover in json file automatically left slash inserted within url

Comment: When you say value is setting to null, are you referring to the manifest-test.json file? How do you recreate the issue, by reloading the page after the form submission?

Comment: yes all the values in manifest file set to null automatically {"name":null,"short_name":null,"description":null,"orientation":null,"start_url":null,"display":null,"background_color":null,"theme_color":null,"icons":[{"src":null,"sizes":null,"types":null}]}

Comment: got it. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

try using:
`json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);` 
this should make it stop adding back slashes on the string.

Comment: thanks slash if fixed but still it automatically set to null @platika

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that what's happening is that whenever you hit that page or refresh the page, the empty form fields are overwriting the previous submission with NULL values.

The first thing I would do is change the conditional you are checking to initiate form validation. So replace

```
if( !empty( $_POST ) )
```

with

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
```

Now the code only runs when a POST request was sent, whereas simply loading or reloading the page would be a GET request.

Next, I would recommend validating each individual field. First of all, you you can't assume that the user filled out each field. Second of all, you need to "sanitize" any bad input. So you could do something like this:

```
$name = (!empty($_POST['name'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['name']) : '';
```

The above is called a ternary expression. If the first part of the expression, which is wrapped in parenthesis, evaluates as true it will return the value after the question mark. If it is false, it will return the value after the semi-colon. So in this case, if the name field is not an empty string $name gets set to `strip_tags($_POST['name'])` 
Otherwise, $name gets set to an empty string.

This is functionally equivalent to

```
if ( !empty($_POST['name'] ) {
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
} else {
    $name = '';
}
```

...but it's much more concise.

I'm not sure if strip_tags() is what you want to do for validation. That's just an example. It depends on what kind of data you are getting, what you intend to do with it, and what risks there might be. If you were storing the data in a database you would do something more effective for validation like use prepared statements.

Regarding the back slashes in the URL, it looks like another user already responded with the solution for that.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks but still automatically seting to null  using if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")

Comment: Check to make sure that the form data is actually POST-ing before you create the JSON. You can use echo or var_dump for that. The boundary between the form tags and the table might be an issue (opening form tag is outside of the table but submit is inside the table)